# What is the Redis command line (redis-cli) continuation character?

Tags: command-line, redis, key-value-store, continuation

I am trying to build a redis 'stored procedure' in lua that will update a keyvalue store when one of the map fields changes, and will also extract a value from another key when said value changes.  I have built this lua(redis) script and it works.

But I discovered that when I try to enter it into the redis-cli, it complains unless I concatenate all the lines of the script onto one long line.  Surely there is a 'continuation character' recognized by the redis-cli (?) but I cannot find it.

Anybody know the continuation character for redis-cli?

Comment: I don't think there is one. You can use a client library from python for example. When you are working with Lua, you need something to do the bookkeeping of `SCRIPT LOAD`/`EVAL`/`EVALSHA` for you. If you just want to tryout some stuff from bash, there are many options. Write to file, produce/consume fifo, put in env.var, use echo plus pipe, etcetera etcetera.

Comment: line breaks are optional in lua. use spaces instead :)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to save the lua script to a file and then use the command line to execute the script in the file as shown here:

http://www.redisgreen.net/blog/2013/03/18/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/

I realize this is not a direct answer to what the continuation character for redis-cli might be (or if it exists).

Comment: The Lua intro for Redis programmers article has been invaluable, but I wanted to have a single sha key and use redis to lookup the functions, which is working except for the difficulty loading these scripts :-(

Comment: I was able to store the lua script in a file, and load it into redis, referring to the loaded script using the SHA key.  And I just combined all the lua lines into one long line.

Comment: line breaks in lua are equivalent to spaces, (except that they also end single-line comments), so if you remove or convert any such comments you can gave a single-line lua script.  but seriously